# most explicit specification in specification pattern for strategy

Tags: design-patterns, factory-pattern, strategy-pattern, specification-pattern

say I have a lot of business logic to determine app behavior based on multiple factors. Also, I have some really good places where I know I can replace the behavior with a strategy pattern. Also, considering I'm trying to leverage various patterns to solve a problem

- strategy pattern
- specification pattern
- factory pattern

is it possible to use the specification pattern for determining a strategy in a factory and retain Open Closed Principle?

I have a factory and I find myself creating switch statements just like the former code to pick the correct strategy.  This seems counter productive.

I want to push all these logical decisions off to specifications but then the problem arises as to ordering the specifications or picking the most explicit specification first.

Any idea how to solve this?

Comment: It would be great if you post some code :)

Answer (score 0):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

using static BeyondOOP.Gender;

// having to make decisions based on logic
// control flow without all the nested if then
namespace BeyondOOP
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var people = new List<Person>
            {
                new Person("Bill", new DateTime(1940, 10, 10), Male),
                new Person("Jill", new DateTime(1950, 10, 10), Female),
                new Person("Mary", new DateTime(2015, 10, 10), Female),
                new Person("Gary", new DateTime(1970, 10, 10), Male),
                new Person("Greg", new DateTime(1980, 10, 10), Male),
                new Person("Susan", new DateTime(2013, 10, 10), Female),
                new Person("Gabe", new DateTime(1999, 10, 10), Neutral),
                new Person("Barbie", new DateTime(2000, 10, 10), Female),
            };
            var greeter = new PersonGreeter();
            people.ForEach(greeter.Greet);
        }
    }

    // a little 'generics' flair
    // a 'predicate' is just a way
    // to predetermine true false
    interface IPredicate<T>
    {
        bool Matches(T value);
    }

    // this is just a simple DTO
    // Data transfer object, fancy for value container
    // it's just a way of passing values around
    class Person
    {
        public string Name { get; }
        public DateTime DateOfBirth { get; }
        public Gender Gender { get; }

        public Person(string name, DateTime dateOfBirth, Gender gender)
        {
            Name = name;
            DateOfBirth = dateOfBirth;
            Gender = gender;
        }
    }

    enum Gender { Male, Female, Neutral }

    // some prefabed predicates for 'Person'
    class OldManPredicate : IPredicate<Person>
    {
        public bool Matches(Person value) =>
            (DateTime.Now.Year - value.DateOfBirth.Year) >= 60 && 
                value.Gender == Gender.Male;
    }

    class MinorPredicate : IPredicate<Person>
    {
        public bool Matches(Person value) =>
            DateTime.Now.Year - value.DateOfBirth.Year < 18;
    }

    class ToddlerPredicate : IPredicate<Person>
    {
        public bool Matches(Person value) =>
            DateTime.Now.Year - value.DateOfBirth.Year > 2 &&
            DateTime.Now.Year - value.DateOfBirth.Year < 4;
    }

    class BabyPredicate : IPredicate<Person>
    {
        public bool Matches(Person value) =>
            DateTime.Now.Year - value.DateOfBirth.Year <= 2;
    }

    class TruePersonPredicate : IPredicate<Person>
    {
        public bool Matches(Person value) => true;
    }

    class GreetAction
    {
        public Func<Person,bool> Predicate { get; }
        public Func<Person,string> Messager { get; }

        public GreetAction(Func<Person, bool> predicate, 
            Func<Person, string> messager  )
        {
            Predicate = predicate;
            Messager = messager;
        }
    }
    class PersonGreeter
    {
        // someone may say that if you're using Func
        // why do you go through the trouble of the extra
        // classes. Predicate classes can be added freely
        // Only this factory class needs to be changed
        // and if I was to create a factory for the predicates 
        // and messagers then no changes would be neccessary
        private readonly List<GreetAction> _greetActions =
            new List<GreetAction>
            {
                // these have to be ordered
                // so they don't conflict or override
                // intended behavior
                // MinorPredicate is < 18 but babies and toddlers are also
                // less than 18, they need to preceed minors to work
                new GreetAction( new OldManPredicate().Matches, 
                    p => $"{p.Name}, you're getting up there!"),
                new GreetAction( new BabyPredicate().Matches,
                    p => $"{p.Name}, time to change the diaper!"),
                new GreetAction( new ToddlerPredicate().Matches,
                    p => $"{p.Name}, look, you're walking!"),
                new GreetAction( new MinorPredicate().Matches, 
                    p => $"{p.Name}, no, you may not have beer!"),
                // you need a default action
                // this is the same as a 'Null Pattern'
                new GreetAction( new TruePersonPredicate().Matches,
                    p => $"{p.Name}, hello there!"),
            }; 

        public void Greet(Person person) => 
            Console.WriteLine(_greetActions
                .First(p => p.Predicate(person))
                .Messager(person));
    }
}
```